# LAStools menu seems to be incomplete in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, installation, lidar, mac, lastools

I am using QGIS 2.18.2 Las Palmas on a MacBook Pro running OSX 10.13.1 High Sierra.
I followed Martin Isenburg's instructions [how to install LAStools toolbox in QGIS](https://rapidlasso.com/2013/09/29/how-to-install-lastools-toolbox-in-qgis/)
and the LAStools menu is available under the "Processing > Toolbox" menu as it should be.

However, the number of tools (algorithms?) available to me in the menu is, I think, smaller than it should be. My LAStools installed menu shows 13 tools or menu items; the example in Mr. Isneburg's instruction shows at least 32 items.

Here is a screen shot of what I have:

[image: LAStools menu after I installed it]

And here is what Mr. Isenburg's image, from his instructions, shows that I should have:

[image: LAStools menu as seen in tutorial]

How do I get more of the menu items, as shown in the tutorial's screenshot?

Update 2017-11-28. I found that some files in the LAStools folder are zipped.

[image]

[image]

Should I go unzipping these files in order to have a proper installation of LAStools?

Comment: I found this in the LAStools installation guide comments: "You can compile the open source LAStools on OSX. But those are a lot fewer." (Martin Isenburg). It's four years ago, though, so I would hope that more tools are now available for people using LAStools on Mac OSX.

Comment: Here is a good discussion about getting all the LAStools available to Mac OSX users:  https://rapidlasso.com/2013/09/29/how-to-install-lastools-toolbox-in-qgis/comment-page-1/#comments

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One needs the program called "Wine" in order to have all the geoalgorithms of LAStools available to QGIS on the Mac OS X. 
In accordance with information gleaned from the discussion threads at [rapidlasso.com/2013/09/29](https://rapidlasso.com/2013/09/29/how-to-install-lastools-toolbox-in-qgis/comment-page-1/#comments) and from [Google Groups - Martin Isenburg post 2017-01-08](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/lastools/3dBEXnQgWmg/discussion), I first downloaded and installed XQuartz, because for the latest version of Wine, XQuartz version 2.7.7 or later is required. XQuartz download was [at this page](https://www.xquartz.org/).
I downloaded Wine from  [Wine for Mac OS X](https://wiki.winehq.org/MacOS).

Then I booted up QGIS and activated the Processing -> Options menu (by clicking on the word "Processing" in the menu bar at the top of the QGIS window). In the Processing Options window, I expanded the "Providers" list (by clicking on the little gray arrow to the left of the word "Providers") and expanded the "Tools for LiDAR data" list. 
[image: Processing options window in QGIS]

I double-clicked in the invisible field to the right of the phrase "Wine folder" - it doesn't look like anything is there until you click there. This opened an ellipsis tool (the **...** symbol) which I clicked on to open a Finder window in which I was able to find and select the folder in which the Wine application is located. (In my case, it is simply the "Applications" folder.)
Now with the file path in the field, I clicked in the field to put the cursor there, and then pressed **Return** [it may be **Enter** on your keyboard]. This set the file path.
[image: Processing options window 02]

If you forget to do that last step, the path will not be set and therefore the fix will not work.

After I carried out this procedure, a fuller complementof LAStools geoalgorithms - 77, apparently - is available (as opposed to 23 before).

Answer (score 0):

You only need to uncompress the folder QGIS_2_0_toolbox.zip!

Comment: Thank you @Roberto Mallorca. However, unzipping the folder "QGIS_2_0_toolbox.zip" did not lead to an increase in the number of algorithms or tools available under LAStools. I wonder if I should unzip all the folders?